# 2002 Chevy Chasis on a motor home

Tags: fuel-system, pump

How many book hours to change the fuel pump do you normally charge?  We have to drop the tank, we know that for sure

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: book time plus extra for rusty bolts.

Comment: @SolarMike - Book time is book time, regardless of rusty bolts ... I mean, you might have to pay to *replace* the rusty bolts, but it won't add to the book hours.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 that must depend on location then, as book time is based on new cars, all equipment available and no rusty bolts that need re-tapping, rewelding etc unless you lot do work for free...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the tank size and if it has a shield, 3.0-4.2 hours book non-warranty.

I can't say if the "motor home" creates additional access issues.

No accounting for rusty nuts . . .

Comment: Motor home could be too large to fit on a standard lift. So you’d want to factor that into the estimate.